# how to get onkeydown event of Y key on YES button of modal pop up

Tags: jquery, jsf

My scenario is  to display a modal pop up with YES and NO Button.
either clicking Yes button or pressing "Y" it should performed desired action and similarly for No button.

`Main.xhtml`

```
    <rich:popupPanel id="popupOne" modal="true" show="#{demoBean.isTrue}">
    <a4j:outputPanel id="popupTwo" >
      <ui:include id="modalPopUp" src="/MyXhtml.xhtml">
      </ui:include>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
    </rich:popupPanel>
```

`MyXhtml.xhtml`

```
    <a4j:outputPanel id="panelForYes" >
    <h:outputText id="errorMsg" name="errorMsg"  class="pop_outputText" value="#{demoBean.messages}" />
                    <a4j:commandButton id ="btnOne" 
                                       action="#{demoBean.yesAction}" 
                                       value="YES" 
                                       oncomplete="closePOPUP()">   
                    </a4j:commandButton>
    </a4j:outputPanel>


    <a4j:outputPanel id="panelForNo" >
                    <a4j:commandButton id ="btnTwo" 
                                       action="#{demoBean.noAction}" 
                                       value="No" 
                                       oncomplete="closePOPUP()">   
                    </a4j:commandButton>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
```

jquery function

```
jQuery(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (document.activeElement.tagName == "INPUT") {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        if (e.which == 89) {
            document.getElementById('btnOne').click();
        }
        if (e.which == 78) {
            document.getElementById('btnTwo').click();
        }

    }
});
```

now problem is i am not able to bind "Y" key event with YES button of modal pop up.

above jquery works well but even if model pop up doesn't come up, "Y" key event invoke my action if it is pressed. how to prevent this scenerio ? how to attach "Y" event to YES button of modal pop up only ?

Answer (score 0):

change your code `which` to `keycode`

```
 jQuery(document).keydown(function (e) {
     if (document.activeElement.tagName == "INPUT") {
         // do nothing
     } else {
         if (e.keyCode == 89) {
             document.getElementById('btnOne').click();
         }
         if (e.keyCode == 78) {
             document.getElementById('btnTwo').click();
         }

     }
 });
```

> Here  is a [**Jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hkmkmx8s/1/)

Comment: but again  it will  invoke action whether pop up comes or not. I want to perform "keydown"  when pop up comes.

Comment: wrap your code inside a check that if popup is visible then only it should work